# Django apps have circular dependency, causes foreign key models not to migrate

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have two django apps that have foreign keys to each other

An **api** app and another app called **blog**

Here is my models.py for the blog app

```
class Post(models.Model):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=False, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', related_name='authors')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='tags')
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    # store table of contents as JSON
    table_of_contents = models.TextField(default=dict)

    # s3 link to thumbnail
    thumbnail = models.URLField(max_length=300)

    # each post belongs to a blog
    blog = models.ForeignKey('api.Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, default='')

    # store markdown as text
    content = models.TextField(default='')

    # link to post
    url = models.URLField(default='')


    # for json serialization
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "title": self.title,
            "slug": self.slug,
            "authors": [ author.as_dict() for author in self.authors.all() ],
            "tags": [ tag.as_dict() for tag in self.tags.all() ],
            "date_published": "01/01/2001",  
            "table_of_contents": self.table_of_contents,
            "thumbnail": self.thumbnail,
            "id": str(self.uuid),
        }
    
    def __str___(self):
        return self.title


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blog = models.ForeignKey('api.Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)


    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "profile": self.name
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    blog = models.ForeignKey('api.Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And my models.py for my "api" app

```
class Blog(models.Model):

    # Foreign key to the associated tenant in case we need to changve schema_name
    tenant = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tenant_blog", default=0)

    class Templates(models.TextChoices):
        SAAS = 'SAAS'
        CHANGELOG = 'CHANGELOG'
        HELP = 'HELP'
        DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT'
        PERSONAL = 'PERSONAL'

    class CTAS(models.TextChoices):
        DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT'
        NEWSLETTER = 'NEWSLETTER'
        
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=False)

    schema_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    useCustomDomain = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    customDomain = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    landing_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    landing_subheader = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    # choose template from the list
    template = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=Templates.choices, default=Templates.DEFAULT)

    url = models.URLField(max_length=300, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs')

    posts = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Post', related_name='posts')
    featuredPosts = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Post', related_name='featured')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Author', related_name="blog_authors")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("blog.Tag", related_name="blog_tags")

    # call to action (newsletter or sign up)
    ctaType = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CTAS.choices, default=CTAS.DEFAULT)

    # display options
    defaultModeLight = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showThemeToggle = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showSpotlight = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showFooter = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showPoweredByBadge = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showCTA = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    page_views_used = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    # Is the blog up/accesible to the public?
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

As you can see both apps have foreign keys that depend on each other which leads to a circular dependency.

When I run `makemigrations` and `migrate` I get `relation "blog_author" does not exist`

I have already tried removing just the foreign key fields, making migrations, adding them back and re-making migrations. But I get the same `relation "blog_author" does not exist` error...

How do I get Django to migrate without running into this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to your question:

When you define a `ForeignKey` relationship on an object, Django will automatically create a way to access those relationships from your other model. Since you're defining the `ForeignKey` on `Post`, `Author`, and `Tag`, you don't need to define the `ManyToMany` relationship from the `Blog`.

If you have a `Blog` object, you can access the posts, authors, and tags associated to the the blog by doing: `blog.[modelname]_set`. For example, to access all the posts associated to a blog post, you can do `blog.author_set.filter...`.

If you want to specify the names of these properties, you can use the `related_name` field for the `ForeignKey` field.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('api.Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, related_name="authors")
```

That way you can now do `blog.authors.filter...` if you have the blog object.

##### Some tips that aren't related to your question:

1. Instead of setting a default value of 0 for a `ForeignKey`, it would be much better to just allow that field to be nullable:

```
blog = models.ForeignKey('api.Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="authors")
```

Either that, or remove both `null` and `default` such that you get an error when you try to add an author/post/tag without a blog (if every author/post/tag has to always have a blog associated to it).

2. Your `related_name` field on the `ManyToMany` relationship between posts, tags, and authors are wrong. `related_name` is how you access this relationship from the *other* model. So instead of:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='tags')
```

It really should be:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='posts')  # This means if you have a `Tag` object, you can do `tag.posts` to get all the associated `Post`s
```

3. For your property names, I'd pick either going all snake case or all camel case instead of a mixture of both (which is what you currently have). I prefer using snake case since that's how most Django/Python properties are.
4. For your `table_of_contents` JSON property, you should use `JSONField` (read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField)) instead of a `TextField`

Comment: my saviour, thank you for the detailed answer